# MSAL Redirects with hash in url

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm currently working on an application in angular 6 which uses AAD to authenticate users. Here i have used the library [azure/msal-angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) to connect to AAD v2. I've initialized the library with my client id as prescribed in the readme for the project, and i can login just fine.

The problem is: 
After i login i've setup a redirect url to: `http://localhost:4200/account` the landing page after login, where i want the user to come after a successful login. Here i've specified the route as such:

```
{ path: 'account', component: AccountDetailedComponent }
```

Which is fine, except the redirect url from AAD navigates to `http://localhost:4200/account#id_token=xxxxx` and for the life of me, i cannot get rid of the hashbang and id_token.

I would expect the id_token=xxxx to be a query param like so:

```
http://localhost:4200/account?id_token=xxxx
```

which would make my route match, but it doesn't, and therefore the route becomes invalid.

***My question is: How can i solve the route to match the specified route?***

I have read about matchers in routes, but can it really be that i should make regex' for matching a common redirect route? I don't see any option in the interface to remove this hashbang nor in the library.

**Edit**

*The reason for thinking it was a route mismatch was, i got redirected to login page again, after the initial redirect to /account. It would flash /account#id_token=xxxx then redirect to login page again. My answer below describes the problem solved.*

Hope you can help.

Kind regards Chris

Comment: Can you update your question with Redirect URIs values from App registrations and `redirectUri` value from MSAL config in your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Actually i've solved the "problem". It was an error on my part, i manually called msalService.loginredirect() in my component oninit, and when i got redirected back to my page, it would automatically call oninit again, and cause an infinite sequence of logging in. I'll post a complete answer underneath shortly.

Comment: You posted a question about hash in url, then you wrote an answer about infinite redirecting... I don't get it...

Comment: oh i see i forgot the add the last part in, im so sorry about that. I did not think this was relavant to my problem at the time. I'll update my question to reflect the problem to full extend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So i've actually solved my own question. The mistake i made was calling `msalService.loginredirect()` manually from within ngOnInit(). When the redirect to microsoft's page occured, i would login, and afterwards get sent back to my application. This would invoke the same `msalService.loginRedirect()` from the ngOnInit method, and thereby never get to the actual redirect.

From what i've been able to understand, the correct way of handling the login, is simply to apply a `canActivate: [MsalGuard]` on the specific route, and let the guard handle the redirect to the login screen, and when you come back, it'll redirect to the specified path without the hash.

I hope this helps others that tried doing what i did. I can elaborate more on my solution if anyone finds this confusing.

Kind regards Chris

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your setup?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What do you want to know? :)